# Change round parentheses around the type into square ones

Tags: bibliographies, parentheses

I am making the bibliography using the package `apacite` as it is working very well (in my opinion). There were just some issues in the translation (using `babel` package) which I redefined to make sure the translation is what it has to be.

Now I have one little issue still: the type of the source is printed between round parentheses "(" and they should be square "[".
Redefining with

```
\renewcommand{\BBOP}{[}
\renewcommand{\BBCP}{]}
```

didn't make sense as all brackets turned into "[" (even those who had to stay "(" ) except those that I wanted to change.

Is there any comparable command to change the parentheses around the type of source??

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}%

\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

\AtBeginDocument{ %to adapt the wrong translation
\renewcommand{\BRetrieved}[1]{Geraadpleegd op {#1} via\ }
\renewcommand{\BRetrievedFrom}{Geraadpleegd via\ }
\urlstyle{same}
}
```

Now I get:

Claessens, T. (2015). Toegepaste stroming- en energieleer **(Syllabus)**. Universiteit Gent, Faculteit Ingenieurswetenschappen en Architectuur.

And I want to have:

Claessens, T. (2015). Toegepaste stroming- en energieleer **[Syllabus]**. Universiteit Gent, Faculteit Ingenieurswetenschappen en Architectuur.

The bib entry is as follows:

```
@TechReport{Claessens, 
   author = {Tom Claessens}, 
   title = {Toegepaste stromings- en energieleer}, 
   institution = {Universiteit Gent, Faculteit Ingenieurswetenschappen en Architectuur}, 
   year = {2015}, 
   type = {Syllabus} 
}
```

Comment: See the `\bibpunct` macro that comes with the `apacite` style, perhaps.

Comment: Please post the code for the Claessens bib entry. It's important to know in which field the "Syllabus" string occurs.

Comment: @Mico: I use JabRef for the bibliography. Don't know what code it generates, but the string is in the "type = "- field:

@TechReport{Claessens,  author =      {Tom Claessens},
  title =       {Toegepaste stromings- en energieleer},
  institution = {Universiteit Gent, Faculteit Ingenieurswetenschappen en Architectuur},
  year =        {2015},
  type =        {Syllabus}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look to the generated bbl-file, you will find the word "Syllabus" in the command `\APACbVolEdTR {}{Syllabus}`. By renewing this command (defined in `apacite.sty`), you can replace the parentheses by brackets. Applied on the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand{\BRetrieved}[1]{Geraadpleegd op {#1} via\ }
\renewcommand{\BRetrievedFrom}{Geraadpleegd via\ }
\urlstyle{same}
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\APACbVolEdTR}[2]{%
\ifx\@empty#1\@empty
    \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
    \else
        {[#2]}%
    \fi
\else
    [{#1}%
    \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
    \else
        \unskip; {#2}%
    \fi
    ]%
\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nocite{Claessens:2015,Stackex:304462}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

The bib-file `Bibliography` has the following content:

```
@Online{Stackex:304462,
author = {{TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange}},
title = {Change round parentheses around the type into square ones},
year = {2016},
month = {april},
day = {15},
url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304462/change-round-parentheses-around-the-type-into-square-ones},
urldate = {18 juni 2016},
}

@TechReport{Claessens:2015,
author = {Tom Claessens},
title = {Toegepaste stromings- en energieleer},
institution = {Universiteit Gent, Faculteit Ingenieurswetenschappen en Architectuur},
year = {2015},
type = {Syllabus},
}
```

All this will give the required result.

[image: Result]